# Replication between two SolrCloud instances

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

We are trying to setup DR site with SolrCloud running in both data centers. Currently we have solr 4.3.1 running with 3 zookeeper instances and 3 solr instances. We are planning to have similar SolrCloud in our DR site.

- What is the best way to replicate data between primary and secondary SolrCloud instances ?
- At a time only one site will be primary so is there any way to make one side master and other slave ?
- If one site is down how to replicate data when it comes up again ?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on the lucene-solr-user mailing list and didn't get a very satisfying answer either.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201403.mbox/%3C607374904-1394026856-cardhu_decombobulator_blackberry.rim.net-778357616-@b1.c2.bise6.blackberry%3E

The best solution Ive come up with is keeping hypervisor-level replication copies of each Solr/Zookeeper VM in the SolrCloud instance such that they can be stood up whole as an antire cluster at the colo with minimal data loss.